# Externalize parameters description in Argo Workflows

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows

is there a way to fetch a description from a yaml file and add it to parameters description in Argo Workflow?
Example with the help of helm:

```
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: param-name
      description: 
      {{ .Files.Get "files/some-description.yaml" | indent 10 }}
      value: 0
```

In this case it doesn't work, but is working when I want to add some script inside a container, which is in external file

```
    command:
      - bash
    source: |
   {{ .Files.Get "files/some-script.sh" | indent 10 }}
```

The other concern is how to get a specific line from yaml, assuming that yaml contains all used descriptions for all workflows, which would look like this:

```
description1:
  "some description 1"
description2:
  "some description 2"
```

Is something like this possible in Argo?

thanx