# How to reuse enum across Argo workflow templates?

Tags: argo-workflows

Say I have a parameter with a big enum:

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/v3.4.13/api/jsonschema/schema.json

apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: time-zone-parameter
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: time-zone
        description: Time zone
        enum:
          - 'Africa/Abidjan'
          - …
```

Is it possible to reuse this enum in another `WorkflowTemplate`? I'd rather not have to copy and paste it all over the place.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77322340/96588).